# Why can't I insert my data into my MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have exported one of my collections from `MongoDB` and it looks like the following:

```
[
{
    "_class": "test.Tag",
    "title": "My Title",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "637a2bc4a9c297b306dd0be9"
    }
}
]
```

Now, I want to add another item to this collection.
I have created a json file exactly in the same format.
However, when I use the following command:

```
db.tag.insertMany([{"_class": "test.Tag",  "title": "New Title","_id": {"$oid": "637a4171833047f9e046f3c9"}}])
```

I get the error:

```
MongoBulkWriteError: _id fields may not contain '$'-prefixed fields: $oid is not valid for storage.
```

I found a couple of similar questions on stackoverflow, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708844/export-from-mongodb-cloud-into-local-mongodb-oid-is-not-valid-for-storage-e), but they didn't help me.

How should I insert something in my database?
When I use MongoDB Compass, there is no problem. It works. But when I try it on my real database on the server, it doesn't work.
If it helps, I am using `Mongo` version 6.0.1.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `db.tag.insertMany([{"_class": "test.Tag",  "title": "New Title","_id": ObjectId("637a4171833047f9e046f3c9")}])`

Comment: @nimrodserok I had tried that, but I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" at the end of my input.

Comment: Which tool do you use to insert the data?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I actually use just Windows CMD. I connect to my server using SSH and then by run commands like "docker exec -it mongodb mongosh --port 27017 -u "user" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"", then "use myDatabase" and then I try to run the above command to insert something into my database.

Answer (score 0):

In the legacy mongo shell there is no helper for extended json format , but in mongosh you can use [EJSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#ejson.deserialize) to deserialize the extended json and insert it as follow:

```
    > db.test4.insertMany([EJSON.deserialize(  {"_id": {   "$oid": "637aa8243d58f36141e59c8d"} } )])
    {
     acknowledged: true,
     insertedIds: { '0': new ObjectId("637aa8243d58f36141e59c8d") }
    }
    >
```

( The legacy mongo shell was deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 and removed in MongoDB 6.0 )